# SQL Server 2012 password hash not matching

Tags: c#, sql-server, parameters, sha

I'm no doubt doing something daft, but I'm struggling here!

Upgrading security on a users table. Converting all existing passwords using sqls built in hashbytes pw, for now not using salt until I can get this working.

Table: admin has 4 records

Current password: admin.password='test'

```
update admin 
set passwordenc = hashbytes('SHA2_256', password);
```

`passwordenc` is of type `varbinary(50)`.

Entry now:

```
admin.passwordenc is 0x9F86D081884C7D659A2FEAA0C55AD015A3BF4F1B2B0B822CD15D6C15B0F00A08
```

which is what I want.

I have a .net cshtml website with login, some code:

```
var uname = Request["username"];
var upass = Request["password"];
var adsql = "select user_id, firstname, surname, profile, username from admin where username=@0 and passwordenc= hashbytes('SHA2_256', @1) ";
```

No records are found.

In dev tools in Chrome I can see that 'admin' is passed across for username, and 'test' for the password.

SQL Server Profiler shows:

```
exec sp_executesql N'select user_id, firstname, surname, profile, username from admin where username=@0 and passwordenc= hashbytes(''SHA2_256'', @1) ',
                   N'@0 nvarchar(5),@1 nvarchar(4)',@0=N'admin',@1=N'test'
```

In my app, if I try this:

```
var adsql = "select user_id, firstname, surname, profile, username from admin where username=@0 and passwordenc=hashbytes('SHA2_256', '"+ upass+"') ";
```

It works.

And the profile log

```
exec sp_executesql N'select user_id, firstname, surname, profile, username from admin where username=@0 and passwordenc=hashbytes(''SHA2_256'', ''test'') ',N'@0 nvarchar(5),@1 nvarchar(4)',@0=N'admin',@1=N'test'
```

Similarly, if I do this

```
var adsql = "select user_id, firstname, surname, profile, username from admin where username=@0 and passwordenc= 0x9F86D081884C7D659A2FEAA0C55AD015A3BF4F1B2B0B822CD15D6C15B0F00A08 ";
```

passing a hardcoded hash it also works.

So passing 'test' in a non parameterised was works, as does checking the hash, but @1 doesn't, and can't see nowt wrong in profiler. Have tried faffing about with the convert function incase its checking a string against a binary but get same results.

What daft thing am I doing wrong?

Comment: `VARCHAR` != `NVARCHAR`. The string must be converted to bytes first before it can be hashed. Your example uses the hash for `VARCHAR` (some single-byte encoding depending on your collation); the parameterized string uses `NVARCHAR` (UTF-16). The latter is the sane thing to do if you don't want to run afoul of collations -- your existing, stored hash is arguably wrong. In a constant (bad, wrong, don't use string interpolation for queries, use parameters!) `NVARCHAR` constants must be preceded with `N` (`N'test').

Comment: This is *NOT* an appropriate method to hash passwords and **broken**. It can be broken easily by calculating the hash all possible password combinations until one is found. Passwords should be *salted*, then hashed for at least 1000 iterations. This is *already* provided by the [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes(v=vs.110).aspx) class in .NET. There is absolutely no reason to reinvent the wheel

Comment: **Why** create a custom security mechanism when ASP.NET *already* provides strong authentication and authorization?

Comment: BTW no repro. The function returns the same binary hash if the *same* text values are used. It does not and *should* not if ASCII and Unicode are mixed

Comment: Legend, simple as that. I will be salting, I just wanted to sort out the above first.

Comment: @user3442107 so, you'll send a **cleartext** password to the server, and hash it only once on the server. Allowing anyone to sniff passwords with eg SQL Server Profiler or any network analzyer. When secure alternatives are already available. Why ?

Comment: Need to maintain compatibility with a classic ASP site, and cannot install any dll on IIS. If someone is able to use SQL profiler or get around our HTTPS encryption I have bigger problems.